# Django How can I pass a subquery in LEFT JOIN

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models (A,B,C):

```
class A(models.Model):

url = models.URLField()
uuid = models.UUIDField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
id = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(C, to_field='user_id',
                         on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
uuid = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field='uuid',
                         on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
```

and I want to perform the following SQL query using the Django ORM:

```
SELECT A.id, COUNT(A.id), COUNT(foo.user)

FROM A

LEFT JOIN (SELECT uuid, user FROM B where user = '<a_specific_user_id>') as foo
  ON A.uuid = foo.uuid_id 
  
WHERE name = '{}'

GROUP by 1

HAVING COUNT(A.id)> 1 AND COUNT(A.id)>COUNT(foo.user)
```

My problem is mainly with LEFT JOIN. I know I can form a `LEFT JOIN` by checking for the existence of `null` fields on table B:

```
A.objects.filter(name='{}', b__isnull=True).values('id', 'name')
```

but how can I `LEFT JOIN` on the specific sub-query I want?

I tried using `Subquery()` but it seems to populate the final `WHERE` statement and not pass my custom sub-query in the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this in the future. I directly contacted the Django irc channel and it's confirmed that, as of now, it's not possible to include a custom subquery in a `LEFT JOIN` clause, using the Django ORM.